# How can I disable product tabs for specific categories?

Tags: products, rwd, magento-1.9

I'm using the extension easytabs but I don't want to show every tab in every category. What is an easy way to disable my product tabs in specifics categories?

Comment: Are you want this for fronted  or backend?

Comment: @AmitBera backend

Comment: in the phtml file of that specific tab, put a condition for category_ids in which u do not want to display the tab.

Comment: Just change it Display mode Only static block from.. category setting on Display setting tab

Comment: @AmitBera and the products won't show up anymore?